# Heroku CLI won't start

Tags: heroku

I installed the Heroku CLI on Windows 10 but when I tried to open the heroku.cmd in the /bin directory, all I got is this [black window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwnUp.png). Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One can use WMIC (Command samples [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2005/02/23/378726.aspx)) and do something like this:

`wmic process where (processid=PROCID_HERE) get parentprocessid`